# inno setup need help about icon group under start menu

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I'm using Inno setup. I need to put my program icon in the Start menu under my company group.

My #defines:

```
MyAppPublisher = publisher
MyAppName = game name
```

Some example code:

```
[Icons]
Name: {group}\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; IconFilename: {app}\{#MyAppIcon}
Name: {group}\{#MyAppPublisher}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {#MyAppURL}
Name: {group}\{#MyAppPublisher}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {uninstallexe}
Name: {commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Tasks: desktopicon
```

I got

- **start menu**

  - all programs

    - game name

      - publisher

        - game name(game exe)
        - uninstall game name
        - website game name

but what I need is

- **start menu**

  - all programs

    - publisher

      - game name

        - game name(game exe)
        - uninstall game name
        - website game name

What should I do to get the layout I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `DefaultGroupName` like this:

```
[Setup]
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}

[Icons]
Name: {group}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; IconFilename: {app}\{#MyAppIcon}
Name: {group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {#MyAppURL}
Name: {group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {uninstallexe}
```

Comment: can this apply to installed directory name `DefaultDirName={pf}\{#AppPub}\{#AppName}`