# Creating a shortcut icon in a Start Menu subfolder?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create a shortcut icon in a Startmenu subfolder:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commonstartmenu}\MY-COMPANY\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
```

I tried to install it in Windows 7 x64. (Without subfolder it works).

But it does not work in a subfolder! Why not? How can I make it work?

EDIT: I have discovered that a "group" must be defined in the "[Setup]" section:

```
DefaultGroupName=MY-COMPANY
```

and then this can be used as a replacement for the StartMenu folder:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
```

This is strange and goes against the file system logic. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's against Windows guidelines to create folders in the *Start* menu for quite a few years. So do not even try that (Windows 10 might give you troubles if you try).

---

Btw, your script works for me on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: Look at my EDIT in the question. I made this EDIT before I saw your answer.

Comment: That makes no sense. The path resolved is the same. Your post must be missing some information. But if you made it working, good for you. But your should not be doing it anyway.

Comment: But the IS documentation says: "{group} The path to the Start Menu folder". And there are several certified answers  in SO confirming this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377364/inno-setup-need-help-about-icon-group-under-start-menu

Comment: Sure, in past (years ago), start menu folders were common. But Microsoft discourage from using them for quite some time now.

Comment: So why does the IS documentation suggest something which is against Windows guidelines? - And, BTW: Wich is the reason for not creating subfolders in the Start Menu? My StartMenu in Windows 7 is full of Program Groups (i.e. subfolders).

Comment: I do not see the documentation suggesting that anywhere. It gives you an opportunity to do whatever you want to do. It does not mean it's suggesting that. Again, in the past, groups were common, so Inno Setup has some support for them.

Comment: Perhaps you did not see this question: Wich is the concrete reason for not creating subfolders in the Start Menu? My StartMenu in Windows 7 is full of Program Groups (i.e. subfolders). See here: https://i.imgur.com/9AVlT1v.png

Comment: And if you check Microsoft Office icons, you will see that they are **not grouped**. - The reason: Well, it's quite inconvenient to expand the group. And the groups were actually more often abused to include too many unneeded icons (like icons to documentation, web pages, uninstallers, readmes, etc), rather than being used to group related and useful icons. Current guidelines is to only include the main application icon, nothing else => So there's no real need for a group.

Comment: MS Office in my Start Menu has even NESTED Sub-groups: https://i.imgur.com/Qm6M5vF.png

Comment: OK, but that's 8 years old version. - And actually Office is a quite good example of where grouping is wrong. User wants to run Word or Excel, not Office. He/she may not even know that Word and Excel are part of some "Office".

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm just starting to learn how to add the programs in my package to the Start Menu with Inno Setup and I keep finding mentions (usually from you) of "Windows Guidelines" for the Start Menu.  Could you please share a link, because I have been unable to locate such a document?  Apparently, I cannot guess the correct search terms, but they aren't "Windows 10 Start Menu Guidelines" -- that's for certain.